# How do I prove that both solutions to this differential equation $y"+k^2y=0$ are equivalent?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

Consider the following differential equation $y''+k^2y=0$, where $y''$ is the 2nd derivative of y with respect to x. The solution to this equation is $y = A\exp(ikx) + B\exp(-ikx)$. However, another equivalent solution is $y = D\cos(kx+E)$. How do I prove that both solutions are equivalent? Are $A$, $B$, $D$, $E$ complex or real constants?

I have been told that B is the complex conjugate of A, so let $A = a+bi$ and $B = a-bi$, where $a$ and $b$ are real. $$y = (a+bi)(coskx + isinkx) +(a-bi)(coskx-isinkx) = 2acoskx -2bsinkx$$ Let $2a =DcosE$ and $2b=DsinE$ and we can get the answer. Is this working correct?

Comment: First you need to use the Euler's formula:$$e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$$, then recall $$\cos(kx+E)=\cos kx\cos E-\sin kx\sin E$$

Comment: Both are indeed solutions of the DE; both cover all posible initiial conditions $y(0)$, $y'(0)$ by suitable choice of their parameters; and most importantly: With given initial conditions the solution is unique

Comment: Also recall that for the result to remain real (assuming $k$ is real), then $A$ and $B$ must be complex. Furthermore, $A = \overline{B}$, so $A+B$ is real and $A-B$ is purely imaginary.

Comment: Using Frank Lu's comment, you can simply evaluate the solutions and simplify the arbitrary constants to show those equations are solutions of $y'' + k^2y = 0$

Comment: I think your edit is correct, if you bear in mind NasuSama's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the simplified approach of this problem:

We are given that

$$y = Ae^{ikx} + Be^{-ikx}$$

and

$$y = D\cos(kx + E)$$

are solutions of the differential equation $y'' + k^2y = 0$.  We treat $A$, $B$, $D$, $E$ to be any constants (no restrictions).

**First expression**

By Frank Lu's comment, we use [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) for the first expression to simplify the terms, which turns out to be

$$\begin{aligned}
y &= Ae^{ikx} + Be^{-ikx}\\
&= A(\cos(kx) + i\sin(kx)) + B(\cos(-kx) + i\sin(-kx))\\
&= A(\cos(kx) + i\sin(kx)) + B(\cos(kx) - i\sin(kx))\\
&= (A + B)\cos(kx) + (Ai - Bi)\sin(kx)
\end{aligned}$$

Fix $A + B$ to be any constant $C_1$ and $Ai - Bi$ to be any constant $C_2$.  Then, we have

$$y(x) = C_1\cos(kx) + C_2\sin(kx)$$

**Second expression**

For the second expression, we use compound angle identity, which is

$$\cos(kx + E) = \cos(kx)\cos(E) - \sin(kx)\sin(E)$$

The expression turns out to be...

$$\begin{aligned}
y &= D\cos(kx + E)\\
&= D(\cos(kx)\cos(E) - \sin(kx)\sin(E))\\
&= D\cos(E)\cos(kx) - D\sin(E)\sin(kx)
\end{aligned}$$

Treating $D\cos(E)$ and $-D\sin(E)$ as any constants, we see that those two solutions are equivalent (by comparing both simplified equations).

Comment: thank you for the detailed solution. If there are no restrictions on E, it means that E can be complex. how does one calculate cos(E) then? E.g. if E = a + ib, then is cos(E) = cos(a).exp(-b)?

Comment: It can be shown that $\cos{\theta} = \cosh{i \theta}$ through Euler's formula. Furthermore: $\cos{\theta} = (e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta})/2$, for any $\theta \in \mathbb{C}$.